# Hide Header Tags if List in Div is Hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a page with 5 lists that can be filtered by 1 jQuery search box. I have the filter working correctly, but I would like to be able to hide the header tag if all of the list elements are hidden from the filter.

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
<input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here to search..." />
<div class="list">
<h2>
List One
</h2>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="list">
<h2>
List Two
</h2>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

        var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $('#myDiv ul li').each(function(){

             if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) == -1)
                 $(this).slideUp();
             else
                $(this).slideDown();

        });     
    });

});
```

[See this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0hmrsLt/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `li` are `:visible` if not the hide `h2`.

```js
$(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

        var text = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $('#myDiv ul li').each(function(){

            if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) == -1)
                $(this).slideUp();
            else
                $(this).slideDown();

        });
        $('h2').each(function(){
            if ($(this).next('ul').children(':visible').length == 0) {
                $(this).slideUp();
            }else {
                $(this).slideDown();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

```css
ul {
        list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here to search..." />
    <div class="list">
        <h2>
            List One
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="list">
        <h2>
            List Two
        </h2>
        <ul>
            <li>a</li>
            <li>b</li>
            <li>c</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```